# Openshift : MongoDB and Mongoexpress

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, openshift

I have some team members that don't have permission to pull docker image locally on their machine and run as local instance of mongodb and mongoexpress.

So  am planning to deploy as mongodb and mongoexpress as pods in Openshift to access locally. Can anyone provide the steps to do that in Openshift? Or else proper resource where I can find information / steps.

I am new to openshift.

Comment: It is possible to achieve that (run containers locally) with minikube for example. I'll test that and get back to you tomorrow. Just let me know if you will manage to achieve that earlier. Btw, what's the OS your colleagues are using?

Comment: Thank you for that. They are using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone provide the steps to do that in Openshift?

This [tutorial](https://blog.openshift.com/deploying-applications-from-images-in-openshift-part-one-web-console/) explains how apps (containers) are deployed from images in OpenShift

> Or else proper resource where I can find information/steps

It depends on your needs, the main question is if you really need container orchestration tools or no. If you need them then you can consider installing them locally:

- [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/)
- [Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/)

or in cloud:

- [Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/) aka GKE (it allows you creating basic Kubernetes cluster in a few clicks)
- [OpenShift](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/installing/installing_vsphere/installing-vsphere.html) (I haven't been dealing with it yet)

from what I've already seen, Kubernetes provides a lot of [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/) (with examples, etc) on topic.

Last but not least, there is [a really nice step-by-step guide](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way) on how to create Kubernetes cluster from scratch "the hard way" if you need the cluster to be fully managed by you.